# Integral of polynomial factorization

Tags: integration, polynomials

I'd like to integrate a one-dimensional factorized polynomial analytically, i.e.

$$ \int_a^b \prod_{i=1}^n (x-c_i) dx $$

with $a,b,c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
This is possible since the product represents a polynomial, so basically I'm looking to expand

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (x-c_i)$$

similar to the binomial theorem. Can someone provide such an expansion?
Thanks!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it will be :
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (x-c_i)=x^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k \sigma_k(c_1,...,c_n)x^{n-k}$$
Where :
$$\sigma_1(c_1,...,c_n)=c_1+c_2+...+c_n\\ \sigma_2(c_1,...,c_n)=c_1c_2+c_1c_3+...+c_1c_n+c_2c_3+...+c_{n-1}c_n\\
\sigma_3(c_1,...,c_n)=c_1c_2c_3+c_1c_2c_4+...+c_{n-2}c_{n-1}c_n\\\
...$$

If you need more explanations :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: Thanks for the link, your method is indeed Vietas method.